# Cosmos DB - Restore Backup

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have some doubts about Cosmo backup/restore. I already undestand that Cosmos backup is done every 4 hours on Blob Storage. But How can I restore this backup if I need in case of a disaster recovery? It will restore all the engine or I have to create another engine of Cosmos and restore the data?

Comment: As documented, this is not blob storage you can access, and you cannot initiate a restore. You'd need to reach out to Support. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here (not programming-related).

Answer (score 0):

Support will create a new account (if this is what you mean by engine) and restore your data into it. This is process is documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#restoring-data-from-online-backups

Edit: There is a private preview portal for to initiate restores that Support can make available to EA customers. Please contact support and ask for access. Backup intervals and retention are configured by support. Please note that retention beyond the 4 backups is has an additional storage charge but its not expensive.

Hope this is helpful.